# Toggle in loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wish to toggle (show/hide) a list when clicking on a title, but cant get the following to work

I have this:

```
          <!-- Title -->
          <div v-for="(subitem, index) in item" v-if="index === 0" @click="toggle(subitem)">
            {{subitem.system_name}} - ({{item.length}})
          </div>

          <!-- All title items that should expand on click "Title" -->
          <div v-if="subitem.clicked">
            <p>{{subitem.system_name}}</p>
          </div>
```

When clicking on the  im triggering a toggle function called toggle, that sets a property on the item "clicked" to true or false (I should mention that this property does not already exist on the object, and I haven't got the possiblity add it, as we get the JSON from an API)

The toggle function is this:

```
toggle: function (data) {
    data.clicked = !data.clicked;
  },
```

Now, when I do this above, I get an error saying: "Property or method "subitem" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option"

Im guessing I get this because the "clicked" property doesnt exist in the object... So how do I work around this? Can't see any real solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `subitem` in the `v-for` as a single item in the loop, but you are using it outside the element which has `v-for` loop on it. That's the reason you get that warning:

```
Property or method "subitem" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
Make sure to declare  reactive data properties in the data option"
```

So move the `div` you want to toggle inside the `div` which has the `v-for` loop on it

```
      <!-- Title -->
      <div v-for="(subitem, index) in item" v-if="index === 0" @click="toggle(subitem)">
        {{subitem.system_name}} - ({{item.length}})
        
         <!-- All title items that should expand on click "Title" -->
          <div v-if="subitem.clicked">
              <p>{{subitem.system_name}}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And coming yo the 2nd issue, as you mention the subitem obj does not have `clicked` property when you fetch the json from api.

You cannot add root level reactive properties after the vue instance is created.

Since you want to toggle the appeance of the div based on the property `clicked` which is not available at the time vue instance is created you should use `vm.$set()` to add reactive properties or `Object.assign()` to add properties to existing object. See [Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

So in your case

```
toggle: function (data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty('clicked')){
        data.clicked = !data.clicked;
    }else{
        //since its the first time , set the value pf clicked to true to show the subitem
        data = Object.assign({}, data, {clicked: true});
    }
    
  },
```

Comment: Awesome, thx  - However, then im getting an error : data.hasOwnPropery is not a function

Comment: @nuffsaid oh that was a typo. Sry.. it is `if(data.hasOwnProperty('clicked'))`

Comment: Hmm, I can see that it sets the property, however, it doesnt seem to react to in the : <div v-if="subitem.clicked">
              <p>{{subitem.system_name}}</p>
          </div>

Comment: It doesnt show even if the clicked value is set to be true :/

Comment: Seems that : this.$set(data, 'clicked', true); solves the problem, instead of Object.assign()